# Creating pod in swift which have dependency on another objective-c pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, adaptive-cards

[image: Overview of my condition]

As I explained in image I want to create Pod lib in swift which have another Pod lib dependency written in Objective-c. 
Now I know that to use objective-c code in swift we need bridge file and I created it too.
but When I set it into Pod's build phase I got this error`<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`

I got hint in internet that I should put .h file into pod-umbrella.h file, But that also gave me error `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'DemoPod'`

1. Please help me if you had similar issue in past and resolved it.
2. Some hint/suggestions are also welcome.

Here is my demopod project for you if you want to play around. 
[Demo Pod Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k4OQejW-m9Px4w-3fj9eXVHU7NyQ_afK/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT**
As per Ashsis suggestion I added below code into DemoPod.modulemap

```
framework module AdaptiveCard {
  umbrella header "/Users/jageen.shukla/Documents/Project/ai answer/DemoPod/Example/Pods/AdaptiveCards/AdaptiveCards.framework/Headers/ACFramework.h"
  requires ios
  export *
}
```

But still I can not build project because it give me error in target project that can not find module "AdaptiveCard".
[image]

I change code in `DemoPod.modulemap`

```
framework module DemoPod {
  umbrella header "DemoPod-umbrella.h"
  
  // Solution 2
  framework module AdaptiveCard {
      umbrella header "/Users/jageen.shukla/Downloads/DemoPod/Example/Pods/AdaptiveCards/AdaptiveCards.framework/Headers/ACFramework.h"
      export *
      module * { export * }
  }
  // ----
  
  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

Now I am able to compile my project. but I am not sure what I am doing is good practice or not? Plus I am also not know why I have to mention `absolute path` of adaptive card's header file.

Latest code : [Demo_2][4]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xve0DUAy4bQ7sx4d3H8WLbJJwTqlJnCt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I maybe forgetting a step, but think all we had to do was create a .h file matching our pod name, and add it in a "Headers" build phase as a public file.  This is for a binary XCFramework served up as a pod.  May of had to prepend @objc on public functions, but not sure

Comment: Thank for your hit, I tried but no luck :(. what i did is this [1] Create DemoPod.h [2] add #import <AdaptiveCards/ACFramework.h> into that file [3] added DemoPod.h into public header. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridging header is only recommended at App Target and App Test target to access objective c and CPP files in swift. You should use modulemap to expose the Objc and CPP functionality to swift library when it comes to static library or framework. Please check the code implementation how to use modulemap here: https://github.com/ashislaha/Swift-ObjectiveC-Interoperability

Comment: Hi, Ashis  Thanks for your blog and comment, I try to export adaptivecard lib using modluemap, but still project is not compiling. Now it showing error on target project. (It could not find adaptive-card).

Comment: can you mention the error here? which phase the error is coming? compilation error, linking error?

Comment: I believe your answer help me to solve my main issue, but I am not sure I am doing right or not please see my edited question. and let me know your comment.

Comment: do not use "absolute path", use "relative path" with respect to where you define the modulemap, if it belongs to the same folder where your public headers/umbrella header resides, you can directly use them, otherwise use ../../ notition to refer its parent folder and go to the project folder and refer the right directory for those headers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried that but it seems not recognize it, might be I have to set search header path ?

Comment: Basically path is to another pod framework which installed as dependency.

Comment: yes, define properly UHSP (User header search path) to the folder where those headers files reside.

Comment: Understood!, I will try that today. And as i mentioned you helped me to solve main cause of this question so I am closing this, I will create another one if having trouble, and ping you (if required). I must say your knowledge for this is very strong let me know any other blogs I should read to stronger my knowledge, Thanks again.

Comment: sure, I will let you know. Most of the outcomes come via multiple research and understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, bridging headers aren't allowed in frameworks, only in applications.

The detailed documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID130)

The Swift code will be able to access everything from objc that is included in the public umbrella header for your framework where it says

```
// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <YourFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

You'll need to remove the bridging header from where you added it in the Build Settings, in order to get your framework to compile.

what should you do now ?

**do this:**

1. Remove your bridging header file.
2. Remove references to the bridging header file in the build settings for the framework
3. Add the necessary headers to your umbrella file ([Name].h)
4. Make the included files public in the framework's "Headers" section of its "Build Phases".
5. Clean and rebuild.

**Note**: The "umbrella header file" is a file (named [ProductName].h) that generally represents all public headers of a framework. It is usually just a list of #import statements to other headers contained in the framework. In Xcode, if you open UIKit.h, you will see a good example of an umbrella file.

Comment: I tried this steps but as I explained in my question it lead me to another error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'DemoPod' ".

Comment: In your answer you point our this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift#2984801, But I think you want me to read this document right ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: I was not trying to point out that :p, just want to confirm it.

Comment: BTW I tried to put header file into umbrella but it gave me error i mentioned above.

Comment: If you think I did something wrong can you use my demo project, and confirm your solution works ?.

Comment: I will try tomorrow then I will back to you.